# Class not found exception in Java application : can PermGen size be the reason

Tags: jvm, classnotfoundexception, permgen

Can class not found exception be caused due to PermGen size ? If not , then what could be the possible reasons for that when JVM is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

> Can class not found exception be caused due to PermGen size ?

No, and I wonder what could have ever led you to believe that this might be the case!

> If not , then what could be the possible reasons for that when JVM is concerned.

Usually it occurs because of an attempt to load a class which isn't on the classpath (or which doesn't exist at all).

Comment: My leads are having an opinion in the favor of PermGen being the issue. I just wanted to confirm and rule out the possibility.